# Listening to NSTableView's event prevents selection and column drag

Tags: c#, .net, cocoa, mono

I am starting to learn Cocoa and Mono.

I have created an NSTableView which I have populated with some rows of data. Now I want to hook up some methods to the events ColumnDidMove, ColumnDidResize and MouseDownInHeaderOfTableColumn.

But whenever I add a listener to any of these events I am no longer able to select any rows or drag any columns. Clicking column headers for sorting or resizing them works, though.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what the exact correct approach here is, however this might help you.

The events provided by the monomac bindings are implemented 'under the hood' as a generated delegate. The delegate encapsulates a lot of the functionality that you describe in the case of `NSTableView`, including moving and resizing columns.

This is described [here](http://spouliot.wordpress.com/2012/03/26/events-vs-objective-c-delegates/) (refers to monotouch, but the concept is identical).

I think that what happens (and this may be wrong) once you subscribe an event, the delegate gets internally set to a generated implementation that does not provide all the required functionality. See this [relevant bug](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=8679).

You could try subscribing *all* the events that are exposed on `NSTableView` and see if that helps.

Otherwise, the best way may be to get your notifications directly from your own delegate rather than using events, e.g.:

```
public override void AwakeFromNib()
{
    tableView.Delegate = new MyDelegate();
}

private class MyDelegate : NSTableViewDelegate
{
    public override void ColumnDidMove(NSNotification notification)
    {
         Console.WriteLine("column did move");
    }
}
```